# Weka in Eclipse (for my Google App Engine)

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, weka

I have never used Weka, but for my GAE Project I'm going to need it. I checked jar files on Weka website to use in Eclipse but I'm not sure which one should be downloaded. So I checked another web site and there are lots of jar files about Weka. I'm looking for a basic version of it. Could you please tell me which one is best for me. Here the links for download:

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-dev/3.7.5

http://www.cms.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

All files of Weka:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/files/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should download all project, then build it by maven.
You can use SVN to checkout code from this link: 
https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/trunk/weka

Comment: what do you mean by saying download all project. Should I download developer version called "weka-3-7-7jre-x64.exe; 37.7 MB" ?

Comment: Using above link to checkout sourcecode and the build it with maven. You will have the lastest version.

Comment: Hi, I have just edited the link. It works! I have just checkout it